# Use one argument as a value in another when calling function

Tags: kotlin

Assuming that we have function and some simple data classes as parameters:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val surname: String)
data class Contact(val phoneNumber: String, val contactName: String)

fun doSomething(person: Person, contact: Contact) = "Creating contact $contact for a ${person.name} ${person.surname}" // body is not really important here
```

is there any way to do something like:

```
doSomething(person = Person("John", "Smith"), Contact("123 456 789", "${person.name} ${person.surname}")) // where 'person' is somehow reference to the first argument
```

---

I would find this useful in some kind of testing util classes when I would like to have some 'test data preparation' functions

```
data class TestData(val person: Person, val contact: Contact)

fun createTestPerson() = Person("John", "Smith")

fun createTestData() = TestData(person = createTestPerson(), Contact("123 456 678", "${person.name} ${person.surname}"))

// currently I need to do something like
fun currentCreateTestData(): TestData {
    val person = createTestPerson()
    return TestData(person , Contact("123 456 678", "${person.name} ${person.surname}"))
}
```

I know that this example may seem to be trivial and easy to refactor (by creating some additional funtions, calling createTestPerson again etc) but it illustrates the issue I have currently in my legacy project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [Scope Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#scope-functions) that are designed for similar cases

```
fun createTestData() = createTestPerson().let { person ->
    TestData(person, Contact("123 456 678", "${person.name} ${person.surname}"))
}
```